# Separate Nginx Rewrites

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have 2 copies of a site. They use the same rewrite rules. One of the sites is a sub directory within another. I want to know how I can have nginx check if we're going to the sub directory and use those rules before trying to use the generic rules

Here's my nginx.conf

```
location /rock/ {
      rewrite ^/(|/)$ /rock/index.php?request=$1;
      rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)(|)$ /rock/index.php?request=$1;  
    }
location / {
      rewrite ^/(|/)$ /index.php?request=$1;
      rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)(|)$ /index.php?request=$1;  
    }
```

Comment: maybe add `break` to the rewrite rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok since you said it works let me explain what you did, I'll quote them from the wiki page:

First the flag you used which is `break`

**break**:

> completes processing of current rewrite directives and non-rewrite processing continues within the current location block only.

by adding the keyword `break` to any rewrite rule, it tells nginx to stop the rewriting, so even if it matches another location which has a rewrite, it wont run it, that's why it didn't execute the rewrites inside the location `location / { .. }`

Another keyword is `last`,

**last**:

> completes processing of current rewrite directives and restarts the process (including rewriting) with a search for a match on the URI from all available locations.

This one which tells nginx to stop the rewriting and restart rewriting again with the new rewritten URL, this is useful when you have some sort of short URL for example then it's rewritten to the bigger expanded URL, which also has another rewrite to extract the parameters and send them to the php engine.

There's also `redirect` and `permanent` but those are used for redirects.

You can read more about those flags in [the rewrite doc page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), also [the wiki page](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#rewrite) which is "obsolete" but I like it more because it uses simpler language.